# Is NHS reliance on foreign doctors typical?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, healthcare

Most of the United Kingdom's healthcare is provided by the tax funded and state organised [National Health Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Health_Service).  Since it was created in 1948 the NHS has [always required foreign doctors](https://www.theguardian.com/healthcare-network/2014/apr/24/foreign-doctors-vital-nhs).  In 2014 although only 11% of all NHS staff were foreign, [26% of its doctors were non-British](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2014/jan/26/nhs-foreign-nationals-immigration-health-service).

A 2017 report by the [British Medical Association](https://www.bma.org.uk/news/media-centre/press-releases/2017/september/staffing-crisis-in-nhs-laid-bare) found that the NHS is encountering staffing shortages because fewer people are choosing to enter medicine or stay within the NHS.  They put this down to a number of factors; principally increasing job stress, increasing student debt, falling wages, inflexible working hours.

Is the proportion of foreign doctors in the NHS comparable to healthcare systems in other developed economies?  If not, why not?  If yes, is there a reason why developed economies can't produce enough doctors locally?

P.S. In [British English "doctor"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doctor) is used more commonly than ["physician"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/physician).

Comment: The root cause is low NHS pay (I think I posted a politics.SE answer on the topic, with references, earlier). "Foreign doctors" is merely a consequence, via MicroEconomics 101 - you have high demand and low price, so (1) they are trying to solve it by increased supply from hiring point; and in the reverse, (2) foreign doctors very often are more agreeable to lower salaries for a variety of reasons (their home country has lower income level; or the benefit of being in UK serves as extra "incentive" despite lower pay), compared to domestic workforce.

Comment: Where I live (Switzerland), each year more than 600 1st grade university students attempt Medecine, only 120 are allowed to pass to 2nd grade. The country has a lack of physicians (**not** Doctors, which is an academic title and not only in the field of health), and they are heavily imported.

Comment: @Bregalad: One of the meanings of “doctor” in English **is** physician. See, e.g., [the Merriam–Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doctor).

Comment: @chirlu Sure but this **is** still wrong and confusing, and not only english but all languages have the same problem.

Comment: @Bregalad British English defines doctor [first and foremost to mean someone qualified to heal the sick](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doctor).  It is not wrong and confusing in this context.  Having a certain type of degree is the second definition.  The ambiguity is not native to British English or the context of discussing healthcare.  I have added this clarification to the question.

Comment: @inappropriateCode: The history briefly: The first three "degree programs", for lack of a better term, in European Universities were Religion, Law and Medicine. Hence why some religious preachers have the title of Dr. (short for Doctor of Divinity, e.g. Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr.), lawyers with the initials J.D. after their name (Juris Doctor, or Doctor of Jurisprudence), and medical doctors have M. D. after their name(Medical Doctor). However the other two have alternate titles that can be referred to (e.g. Councilor, Reverend/Father, etc.), while physicians don't, hence "doctor" first.

Comment: @sharur "M.D." seems to have a general meaning in US English, but in British it is more specific, and the [proper form of address is "Doctor" (unless they are a surgeon, but that may be changing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(title)#United_Kingdom), then specifying their medical degree; which may or may not be a MD which is a postgrad qualification even within medicine.  In Scotland it tends to be just "Dr. X".  Not "Dr. X MBBS", and then there's a distinction between Dr. Postgrad and Dr. Divinity, the latter often referred to as Rev. instead.

Comment: It's not entirely accurate that availability/production of locally trained doctors/medical practitioners is strictly a problem for the developed world: http://www.who.int/gho/health_workforce/physicians_density/en/ although this is obviously partly driven by migration.

Comment: @Bregalad: The use of "doctor" = physician is neither wrong nor confusing, at least if you're a native speaker.  It's also the norm in American English, and far more common than the use as an academic title, which is generally only used in academic circles.  In fact, any confusion goes the other way: hearing your new neighbor referred to as Dr. Smith, your default assumption is that she's a physician, not a literature professor :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Fist of all, this has nothing to do with English, as other languages have the exact same issue. I always correct people using "Doctor" for a physician, because I think it is confusing. I was extremely confused at the age of 11 the first time when I saw doctors in psychology, philosophy or other stuff. (And that was before I even started to learn English).

Comment: @Bregalad. "Correction" may not be the best word to use, given common and official usage in the UK means that a medical practitioner *is* a doctor. Unfortunately human language is ambiguous.

Comment: @Bregalad: Yes, it IS about English, because "doctor" is the most common term for a physician in English.  It's also the most common use of the word, other uses being reserved to formal academic settings, or to coinages like "spin doctor" that play off the physician definition.  Perhaps other languanges as well, though I'm not fluent enough in any to judge.  You need to correct yourself, not native speakers of the language :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The UK does have one of the highest percentages but not the highest. So yes, the same phenomena is common to plenty of other developed nations, although "typical" might be to much of a strong word. The reasons are likely different for each one of them (see the plot at the end of the answer) but it does not seem to depend on the level of development (check Denmark or Italy by comparison with the UK, for example).

You can see the data in [OECD.stat](http://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?lang=en&SubSessionId=bcf973af-fbe8-4a62-99d2-58841fb76024&themetreeid=-200), more specifically in a query such as [this](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?QueryId=68336#) (change variable to *% of Foreign trained Doctors* to reproduce the data in the following "table").

---

**Country** .............. **% of Foreign trained Doctors**

Israel.....................     57

New Zealand........   42

Ireland..................     41

Australia...............     32

UK........................           28

USA......................         24

Canada................     23

France.................      10

Germany..............     10

Austria..................     5

Denmark...............      5

Italy.......................      <1

---

I've tried to find some explanation to these numbers but even the more obvious seem to somehow elude a reasonable explanation. For example check this bar plot for the number of *Medical Graduates per 100 000 people*. Ireland having more than double the number of graduates, also as almost double the percentage of foreign trained doctors by comparison with the US (check the chart [here](https://data.oecd.org/chart/4JWk)).

[image]

**EDIT:** Apparently this subject has been widely studied in the EU.

[Costigliola (2011)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3405407/), quoting the [World Health Organization](http://www.euro.who.int/en/publications/abstracts/health-professional-mobility-and-health-systems.-evidence-from-17-european-countries-2011) report ["Health professional mobility and health systems. Evidence from 17 European countries (2011)"](http://www.euro.who.int/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/152324/Health-Professional-Mobility-Health-Systems.pdf?ua=1) , argues that:

> Among the most-cited factors for physicians’ mobility is the **financial**
>   **motivation**. As regards the salaries, major differences between
>   European countries can be observed. ...
>
> Another factor influencing physicians to move across borders is the
>   **working environment and conditions**. The economic situation of a
>   country has a major impact on the quality and standards of healthcare
>   facilities and on the social benefits offered for health
>   professionals. ...
>
> **Training and career opportunities** are also among the relevant
>   decision-making factors for physicians who consider leaving their
>   country of origin, either temporary or for a long period of time. ...

... and adds:

> According to a WHO report on healthcare workforce migration in Europe,
>   there are also other factors associated with migration flows that can
>   stimulate migration and affect the choice of a destination country:
>
> - Organizational factors, such as heavy workload, occupational risks, poor management, favouritism or lack of due process, lack of
>     recognition;
> - Healthcare system factors, such as the absence or inadequacy of human resource policies, insufficient funding of health services, and
>     centralised decision-making;
> - General environmental factors, such as poor economic conditions and lack of security.

Specifically for the UK the [NHS seems to be in favor of professional mobility](http://www.nhsemployers.org/your-workforce/recruit/employer-led-recruitment/international-recruitment/mobility-of-health-professionals-across-europe). I would also recommend the [Politico.eu](https://www.politico.eu/) article ["The EU exodus: When doctors and nurses follow the money"](https://www.politico.eu/article/doctors-nurses-migration-health-care-crisis-workers-follow-the-money-european-commission-data/) where this chart can be seen (for some countries it seems to somewhat contradict the OECD data):

[image]

As well as this one that show the sending vs the receiving country for these doctors (EU only):

[image]

Comment: The English-speaking countries probably all have a high percentage because it is easy for doctors to move among them. Learning a foreign language to a degree that you can work as a doctor is not easy.

Comment: France is an outlier in the other direction being below average for both import and production. I guess the missing figure is how many doctors get exported, but availability might also be an explanation.

Comment: Interesting data!  [Also, I found this](https://journal.practicelink.com/vital-stats/physician-compensation-worldwide/).  Average earnings don't seem to explain it much either.  I can't imagine there's a substantial number of say, Danish or Italian specialists in the Netherlands and Australia.

Comment: fyi, Israel is a major outlier because they likely count doctors from enormous former-USSR population, which is specific to that country and not to anything easily genralisable.

Comment: @chirlu: On the contrary, most foreign-born doctors (at least in my experience of the US) tend to come from countries where English is not the first language.  The reason seems obvious: if one trains as a physician (or a scientist, programmer, or other in-demand profession) in a 3rd world country, it's much easier to immigrate to the 1st world, where you can make a lot more money (among other advantages).

Comment: @jamesqf: Yes, but I was thinking of the other direction. It is relatively complicated, and therefore rare, for a doctor to go to (say) Denmark, because of the language; even though Denmark does pay well, too. – For English-speaking countries, the situation is somewhat different because “everyone” speaks at least some English, so there is a basis that they can expand on.

Comment: @chirlu Yes, I agree. I do feel language plays an important role, but it does not explain everything. For example many of the Scandinavian (Nordic) nations also have high percentages (Finland: 19%, Sweden: 27%,  Norway: 38%). The same for Switzerland (27%). By the way, in the plot, if you change the variable to "Foreign-trained doctors by country of origin - Stock" you'll have the absolute values by country of origin. For example Norway has a lot of German, Polish, and Hungarian Doctors.

Comment: @inappropriateCode True, but it does explain some things. For example while checking the data tables I saw many countries with a large percentage of German Doctors. Your table seems to show that by comparison with neighboring countries German Doctors don't make that much. I did a bit more of search and I'll edit the answer in a minute.

Comment: @inappropriateCode southern european average earnings are way way way way lower than other OECD countries, any doctor in medicine of spain or italy would sell it's soul to get a contract elsewhere, or an engineer... or anybody really. the average for a PhD in medicine does not go much beyond the 18.000€/y  - 24.000€/y range unless you're *head of* X (surgery, et).

Comment: @CptEric Interesting.  I wondered if the cost of living was also lower, but according to EU data [and this website](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/index/europe) apparently not.  Italian cost of living is higher than EU average?  That however doesn't explain the difference between say, Sweden and Denmark.  Sweden's GDP per capita is a little higher than Denmark's.  Not enough to explain the difference.  Both countries also seem to swap lots of doctors, according to the above graph.  Curious.  Especially since Danish doctors apparently earn more than Swedish peers.

Comment: @inappropriateCode but denmark hospitals are private, whereas swedish ones are public if i'm not wrong, i bet this makes a difference in favour of sweden.  cost of living in italy (not Rome) and in spain ( not Barcelona) is quite lower than most of europe too, but the salaries are lower than the cost of living. whereas a medical assistant could live well & alone on most EU contries, in spain he most probably can only afford 0.8/0.7 of living expenses.  i always use this one: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/comparison.jsp for comparisions, as it's updated and reviewed by users constantly.

Comment: @inappropriateCode when i talk about private, i mean  about 100% or almost 100% private management ( not private as per where the funds come from), specialized healthcare personnel tends to prefer (when salaries are similar and cost of life too) to work on non business-centered organizations, atleast by demoscopia's poll results on spain.

Comment: @CptEric I [skimmed this](http://www.lse.ac.uk/LSEHealthAndSocialCare/pdf/eurohealth/VOL14No1/VrangbAlk.pdf).  Danish hospitals are not private, they are owned and run by government.  Only 13% of Danes use private healthcare, though more use private insurance to add to public cover.  According to Sweden's website, their healthcare [is mostly tax funded too](https://sweden.se/society/health-care-in-sweden/).  So it's not that?  I'm no expert though, so maybe there's nuance I've missed.

Comment: @CptEric Both Denmark and Sweden healthcare systems are public. I come from a country with a similar system. Services such as administration, cleaning, maintenance, gardening, transportation, etc., can be done by private contractors but they don't own the hospitals, pay the doctors, or do any kind of service related to healthcare, or are able to decide anything pertaining to it. I don't really know of any significant difference between those two public systems, certainly not anything that could justify the subject of this question.

Comment: @inappropriateCode both are public as per "what the user sees", but as far as i know, or as it was reported on a recent article i read, danish hospitals are usually lent/leased to  mixed consortiums or private companies that do the managing, and that includes scheduling rooms, operations, and any non economic personnel management. it's similar to spain, where there's public, public with private management, and private hospitals, but here management also picks the salarial extras. from what i know, on similar countries it comes to personal preference of the personnel regards workplace features.

Comment: @CptEric Yes but that's the equivalent of your company hiring another company to do the office maintenance. The latter is a private service provider that can only make decisions concerning its own contract. Typically in public healthcare systems the patient care is free or close enough. There is no actual income per patient, only a yearly budget for the hospital covered by taxes. When you say an healthcare system is "private" people will be interpreting something very different (the US healthcare and health insurance system for example).

Comment: @armatita completely agree, it can be misinterpreted. what i meant is that  the factors that give the "managing" company that yearly revenue could end affecting the daily professional life of medical personnel, as per restrictions, removal of pluses, medicine purchase preference, vacations / leaves, without affecting the end-user OR the administration directly.

Comment: @CptEric Yes but you are assuming that these administrative teams have far more power than they actually do. They exist in both Denmark and Sweden (in fact Sweden private share is bigger than Denmark but, as far as I know, it still runs on temporary state sponsored contracts), and their business is very similar to the one of a property management company. Things like accepted pharmaceuticals, vacations, and so on, are likely regulated by their national Medics Association (the name depends on the country).

Comment: @CptEric Let me put it another way. The point of these companies is not to make hospitals profitable, it is to run them more efficiently. So if a company gets X per year to manage a given hospital, and somehow manages to spend only X-Y, than the Y is profit. But we are talking about "turning off unused lights", or "buy less expensive pens" kind of management. They have little to no power regarding the actual "business" of the hospital and its workers.

Comment: @armatita if that's how it works in denmark, then my argument is blown away. but in my country they even get to pick surgery timetables and operators.

Comment: @CptEric I don't know the specifics of Denmark. I just presented a "rule of thumb" description for hospital management. You mentioned Spain before so I'm assuming you are Spanish. Spain healthcare system is still heavily public but, as far as I know, there are considerable differences in between regions. I'm guessing this might lead to some considerable internal health tourism. It has its problems but Spain's health system is actually [one of the best in the world](http://thepatientfactor.com/canadian-health-care-information/world-health-organizations-ranking-of-the-worlds-health-systems/).

Comment: @armatita it's one of the best for the users,i agree as one, but for the medical personnel, it's a big and low paid ( compared to peers abroad) mess, hence the flocks of new grads fleeing elsewhere, mostly france, germany, uk and south american countries in need of high qualified personnel.about 2.6M spanish citziens live and work abroad as per end of 2017, compared to early crisis (2009)'s 1.4M.

Comment: I tried cross-referencing it with linguistic similarity or Eurovision voting patterns, but it's too hard to see.

Comment: @chirlu: Given that most immigrant doctors in the UK seem to come from  Greece, Italy, Romania and Spain (according to that final graph), the theory that it's a language-based migration seems false in general. Rather socio-economic conditions and probably ease of migration (EU) are the main factors. The language theory does seem to hold for Austria to Germany though, and perhaps for Belgium to Netherlands, and for Slovakia to the Czech Republic.

Comment: @armatita: did you see any data for where the non-EU NHS doctors come from? Ah, I found a source myself in under a minute https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/CBP-7783

Comment: @Fizz: See also [my second comment above](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27599/is-nhs-reliance-on-foreign-doctors-typical/27600?noredirect=1#comment101959_27600); English is special. But certainly the economy also plays a big part.

Comment: @Fizz The second link in the answer points to a query ("Foreign trained doctors by country of origin") for the OECD.stat database. This includes EU and non-EU for any country available. Choose the country at the top of the table.

Comment: @Fizz Also I think the point chirlu was making is that nowadays most people with higher education have enough English speaking skills to get by. So a Greek person would have a much easier time in the UK or Ireland than in Germany, for example. I can tell by experience that I already make sure that I'm going into an English speaking environment when considering job offers. It takes a lot of effort and time to learn a new language. English is the easy choice when applying internationally.